# Simple, quick webcam viewer for Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, webcam

In Windows XP, there used to be a way to view the webcam (I've forgotten exactly how, but it was there). In Windows 7, this feature doesn't seem to be there, so I'm looking for a simple program to let me view the webcam, and take a picture.

Requirements:

- lightweight
- opens in seconds (or as fast as possible)
- lets me take a picture via the built-in webcam
- runs on Windows 7
- free

A bonus is a timed picture, ie. I choose 5 second delay and the picture is taken after 5 seconds - but if this increases the time for the start-up, I don't want it!

Comment: Do you have VLC on your computer? You can view the webcam and take a screenshot with that, but it's just not lightweight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [WebcamViewer](http://www.bustatech.com/webcamviewer-a-simple-viewer-for-webcam/)

From the Website of Bust a Tech:

> WebcamViewer is a very simple click-and-run application, where you
> don’t have to install the application. Simply download the exe file
> and run the exe file to use the software. You can store it inside your
> harddisk or you can carry it in your pendrive, and run it on any PC
> you want.

[image]

Features:

- free
- can run multiple instances if the program for multiple webcams
- portable
- lightweight
- easy to use
- opens quickly

Answer (score 1):

I would try [Yawcam](http://www.yawcam.com/index.php)

The description from it webpage is:

> What is Yawcam?
>
> Yawcam is a shortening for Yet Another WebCAM software, and that's exactly what it is ;-)
>   More precise Yawcam is a webcam software for windows written in java. The main ideas for Yawcam are to keep it simple and easy to use but to include all the usual features.
>
> Yawcam is completely free to use! ...but if you find this software useful, please consider to make a donation to support cancer research.
>
> Yawcam features:
>
> .: Video streaming
>
> .: Image snapshots
>
> .: Built-in webserver
>
> .: Motion detection
>
> .: Ftp-upload
>
> .: Text and image overlays
>
> .: Password protection
>
> .: Online announcements for communities
>
> .: Scheduler for online time
>
> .: Time lapse movies
>
> .: Run as a Windows service
>
> .: Multi languages

Comment: Yawcam requires Java to be installed and also "requires" WMP9 (although it can do most stuff without WMP9).